# Parse time seconds to clock in Golang

Tags: go

How to parse time seconds to the clock format in Golang?

For example:

```
input: 0      => output: '12:00 AM'
input: 60     => output: '12:01 AM'
input: 60*60  => output: '1:00 AM'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the number of seconds into the [`time.Date`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Date) function:

```
t := time.Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, sec, 0, time.UTC)
fmt.Println(t.Format("03:04 PM"))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/zV720y4E-o